# How to repair exposed waterproofing underlayment caused when removing a slate tile on deck?

Tags: tile

I inadvertently chipped away too much mortar bed, exposing the bituthene waterproofing underlayment, while replacing a slate tile on my deck.  I'm not sure whether to repair with additional thinset mortar when I lay the new tile or apply a silicone roofing sealant before the thinset.

[image]

Comment: "exposing?" or "cutting a hole in?" - kinda makes a huge difference here.

Comment: The tarpaper wasn't torn, but rather I was able to remove the loose mortar, exposing the tarpaper below.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not punctured/pierced the membrane, fill it with mortar/thinset and tile away.

Comment: I noticed that the membrane had inflated due to the hot weather.  A little bit of oozing of tar was noticeable too.  Wouldn't it be safe to cover the membrane with a silicone roofing sealant before laying the thinset?

Comment: If doing anything with a bituthane installation (which is *not* tarpaper) your best, most compatible, bet would be to carefully expose a larger area, clean it carefully, and apply a patch of bituthane, rather than tossing some sort of silicone sealant at it that probably won't bond nearly as well. Bituthane is designed to stick very well to itself.